# Thermalization of BEC dark matter

Tags: dark-matter, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity, axion

In the context of BEC/superfluid dark matter, one of the important requirements is that - within galaxies - dark matter *thermalizes* [1]. Axions are appropriate in this regieme, as their self-interactions provide means to reach a state of larger entropy [2].

My question is *why* is it important that DM thermalize in galaxies. Does thermalization mean to reach a state of thermodynamic equilibrium? If so, is it the nature of the BEC that imposes this constraint or is it observations of DM?

[1]     10.1103/PhysRevD.92.103510

[2]     10.1103/PhysRevD.85.063520